# VBScript to import HTML into Excel and create chart

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel-2010

As you can tell by the following code, I'm new to VBscripting for Excel. I'm simply trying to import an HTML file ("DEMO8.HTM") into Excel and create a chart based on the data in column F. The chart should show up as an object in the sheet created. I'm having a problem getting the 'Chart.Add' syntax to work. Whenever I change it, something else goes wrong. Anyway, here's the code:

```
Dim chtChart

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\DEMO8.HTM")
objExcel.Visible = TRUE

Set chtChart = Charts.Add
With chtChart
    chtChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    chtChart.SetSourceData.Range("'DEMO8'!$F:$F")
    chtChart.Location.xlLocationAsObject

    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'DEMO8'!$F:$F")
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    Selection.Delete
    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 300
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
End With

' Give the user control of Excel
UserControl = true
```

I basically 'Frankensteined' this from various bits of code. It seems to open the HTML file but doesn't create the chart. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is from a .vbs file as opposed to VBA within excel? - because you use createobject you must predefine the values of the xl* constants (xlColumnClustered et al) else they will just be 0 - are you doing this?

Comment: Yes, this is straight VBS. How do I predefine them? ... using DIM? Whenever I did this it errored when I tried to say "Dim (variable) AS Chart" or "As String".

Comment: Easiest way; open up the VBA editor in excel (alt+fll) in the "immediate" window (if you cant see it click view->immediate window) type for example `?xlValue` hit enter; `2` is the value, this is what you need to replace `xlValue` in your script with - do the same for all the xl* contants.

Comment: Just noticed your using naked objects; Charts.Add there is no Charts in VBS it needs to be prefixed with the parent object; objWorkbook

Comment: Now it seems to have a problem with 
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'DEMO8'!$F:$F")
At the: "=Range" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May get you closer to what you want;

```
Dim chtChart, objWorkbook, objExcel

const xlValue = 2
const xlColumnClustered = 51
const xlCategory = 1

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\DEMO8.html")
objExcel.Visible = True

Set chtChart = objWorkbook.Charts.Add

chtChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
chtChart.SetSourceData objExcel.Sheets("DEMO8").Range("F:F")

objWorkbook.ActiveChart.Legend.Select
objExcel.Selection.Delete
objWorkbook.ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
objWorkbook.ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
objExcel.Selection.Delete
objWorkbook.ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
objWorkbook.ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).Select
objWorkbook.ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 300
objWorkbook.ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will convert excel sheet into html:

```
Dim oExcel
Dim objExcelWB
Dim objExcelWS, WScript
Dim strColumnCount, strTotRows, strData, strTable

Dim i, j, objFSO, objtxt
Dim strWbk
strWbk = "<excel sheet path>"
Dim strWsheetName
strWsheetName = "<workbook name>"
Dim strHTMLFile
strHTMLFile = "<html path>"
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Visible = False

Set objExcelWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(strWbk)

Set objExcelWS = objExcelWB.Worksheets(strWsheetName)
'Getting the rows and column count
 strColumnCount = objExcelWS.UsedRange.Columns.Count
 strTotRows = objExcelWS.UsedRange.Rows.Count

strTable = "<table border=""""1"""">"
'Create html table based on content of the excel file
 For j = 1 To strTotRows
  strTable = strTable & "<tr>"
  For i = 1 To strColumnCount
    strData = Trim(objExcelWS.Cells(j, i))
    strTable = strTable & "<td>" & strData & "</td>"
  Next
  strTable = strTable & "</tr>"
 Next
 strTable = strTable & "</table>"
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.FileSystemObject")
 Set objtxt = objFSO.createTextFile(strHTMLFile)
    objtxt.write (strTable)
'Closing the workbook
 objExcelWB.Close
oExcel.Quit
 Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objExcelWB = Nothing
Set oExcel = Nothing
```